# How to prove equivalence of definitions for matrix similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

It seems the most usual way to define matrix similarity is as follows:

"Let $A$ and $A'$ be two n-by-n matrices, we say they are similar if there exist some invertible n-by-n matrix $P$ such that $A=PA'P^{-1}$"

However in my first course of linear algebra we defined it this way:

"Let $A$ and $A'$ be two n-by-n matrices, we say they are similar if there exist two invertible n-by-n matrices $C$ and $D$ such that $A=CA'D^{-1}$"

And I guess the reason we defined it this way was because we were thinking of matrices as representing linear transformations, so from that definition (the latter one) we deduced that if $A$ and $A'$ were two matrices associated to a linear operator in different bases, then $C$ and $D$ were just the change of basis matrices.

Now, what I want to understand is how can I find a matrix $P$, like in the first definition, given the matrices $C$ and $D$ of the second definition, is $P$ a function of $C$ and $D$? I want to prove the equivalence between both definitions, the implication from the first one to the second one is obvious, but I don't realize how to prove the other implication.

Comment: They aren't equivalent. The latter condition is used if you are viewing a matrix as a linear transformation $V \to W$ between two unrelated vector spaces. The former is used if you are viewing a matrix as a linear transformation $V \to V$ with the same domain and codomain.

Comment: A simple test: the alternative definition would allow the determinant to change

Comment: @DustanLevenstein but then if we are in the case of  matrices being seen as endomorphisms,  are those definitions equivalent? And in the affirmative case how can I prove the second one implies the first one?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Your first definition of similarity is the one we obtain if we view a matrix as an endomorphism $V \to V$, allowing for a change of basis. Your second definition is the one obtained by viewing it as a linear transformation $V \to W$, and allowing for independent changes of bases on both vector spaces. You can't separate the definitions of "similarity" from how we view the matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first definition you cite is the usual definition for matrix similiarity, under this definition, two matrices are similar, if they can represent the same linear transformation $V \to V$ under a change of basis, where in domain and codomain the *same basis* is used.

The second definition defines another thing, two matrices fulfilling it are usually called *equivalent*, not similar. Two matrices are equivalent if they can represent the same linear transformation $V \to W$ under a change of basis in domain and codomain, where both bases are unrelated.

For example $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$
and not similar, but equivalent.

Comment: That makes sense, actually I've realized that when we defined "similarity" (the second definition) in our course, we defined if for n-by-m matrices.  In your example, how do you realize those matrices are not similar, how could we prove that we can't find such a $P$ that makes them similar?

Comment: @Eliana They are not similar because they have different sets of eigenvalues ($B$ has $1$ as an eigenvalue while $A$ does not). The are equivalent because you can swap two columns to convert one to the other; this corresponds to right multiplication by the invertible matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.